Mounting QNAP on MacOS taking too long
2x1TB SSDs on RAID 1. I'm trying to mount it on macOS via Qfinder and it is taking too long. 10 minutes so far and counting. Is there something wrong? How long does it take?

Something is wrong.  It should take in the order of maybe seconds.    Googling a bit (I've not used QFinder or QNAP devices, but I do understand NAS's generally - also why this is not an answer) it may be that your QNAP is not connected to the network?   Can other devices on your LAN see the NAS?  Is the LAN port lit up?

Yes, you are right. Something weird happened. It worked when I cancelled it.
